# Extracting response body from service worker fetch event

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-events

I'm trying to enable push notification on my react app (PWA).

This is my service worker file.
I've successfully done so whenever a request is made to a specific endpoint by doing so

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  console.log('Claiming control');
  return self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', async event => {
  const url = new URL(event.request.url);
  //
  if (url.pathname === 'my-endpoint') {
    //I want the notification to display the response data
    event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification('custom title', {
        body: 'custom body'
      })
    );
  }
});
```

The problem is the title and body are currently static. How do I extract the response body and used that to dynamically create custom  notification messages instead?

Comment: I would probably setup a State that holds title and body for the notification. But We need to see some more code to understand what you are asking. Also [react-hot-toast](https://react-hot-toast.com/) is a great library to handle showing notifications to the user with minimal effort. After you set the <Toaster/> element near the top of you application you just make toast() function calls to create a new notification.

Comment: thanks, I'm actually talking about push notification for PWAs